# JSON serialization of Scala enums using Jackson

Tags: scala, jackson

Following this article https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/wiki/Enumerations

The enumeration declaration is as

```
object UserStatus extends Enumeration {
  type UserStatus = Value
  val Active, Paused = Value
}

class UserStatusType extends TypeReference[UserStatus.type]
case class UserStatusHolder(@JsonScalaEnumeration(classOf[UserStatusType]) enum:   UserStatus.UserStatus)
```

The DTO is declared as

```
class UserInfo(val emailAddress: String, val  userStatus:UserStatusHolder) {

}
```

and the serialization code is

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

def serialize(value: Any): String = {
    import java.io.StringWriter
    val writer = new StringWriter()
    mapper.writeValue(writer, value)
    writer.toString
}
```

The resulting JSON serialization is

```
{
    "emailAddress":"user1@test.com",
    "userStatus":{"enum":"Active"}
}
```

Is it possible to get it the following form ?

```
{
    "emailAddress":"user1@test.com",
    "userStatus":"Active"
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
case class UserInfo(
   emailAddress: String, 
   @JsonScalaEnumeration(classOf[UserStatusType]) userStatus:   UserStatus.UserStatus
)
```

The jackson wiki's example is a little misleading. You don't need the `holder` class. Its just an example of a thing that has that element. The thing you need is the annotation

Comment: This works! Also, can I make enums case-insensitive?